# Order realtime updates in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> When I listen for realtime updates in firebase, I want newly added data to come before the old data. Now the newest data comes after the old data until I refresh the page, then everything order in the right order. In this case the class "project" needs to be ordered where the newest projects comes first in real time, and not just when I refresh the page. Thanks for any tips.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if(user){
        document.getElementById('myBar').style.display="inline"
        var userId=firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

        db.collection('projects').orderBy('time', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
                var posttime = change.doc.data().time;
                var downloadlink = change.doc.data().downloadlink;
                var time = posttime.toDate().getDate() + "/" + posttime.toDate().getMonth() + " " + addZero(posttime.toDate().getHours()) + ":" + addZero(posttime.toDate().getMinutes());
                var simplePostTime = posttime.toDate().getDate();
                var dateBeforeGone = new Date().getDate()-1;

                var yourRating;
                var rating=(((1*change.doc.data().oneStar)+(2*change.doc.data().twoStar)+(3*change.doc.data().threeStar)+(4*change.doc.data().fourStar)+(5*change.doc.data().fiveStar))/((change.doc.data().oneStar)+(change.doc.data().twoStar)+(change.doc.data().threeStar)+(change.doc.data().fourStar)+(change.doc.data().fiveStar))).toFixed(1);
                var votes=(change.doc.data().oneStar+change.doc.data().twoStar+change.doc.data().threeStar+change.doc.data().fourStar+change.doc.data().fiveStar);

                if(rating=="NaN"){
                    rating="Not Rated"
                }
                if (change.type === "added") {
                    if(simplePostTime>=dateBeforeGone){

                        var newProjects = "";
                        newProjects = 
                        "<div class='project' id='p-"+change.doc.id+"'>"+

                            "<h4 class='projectOwner'>"+
                                "<i class='fas fa-user'></i>"+change.doc.data().projectowner+
                                "<span class='valueContainer'>"+
                                    "<i class='fas fa-coins'></i>"+
                                    "<span class='projectValue'>10</span>"+
                                    "<i class='fas fa-star-half-alt' id='"+change.doc.id+"' onclick='rateProject(this)'></i>"+
                                "</span>"+
                            "</h4>"+
                            "<div class=projectContent>"+
                                "<div class='projectName'><span>Title: </span>"+change.doc.data().title+"</div>"+
                                "<div class='projectDescription'><span>Description: </span>"+change.doc.data().description+"</div>"+
                                "<div class='projectGenre'><span>Genre: </span>"+change.doc.data().genre+"</div>"+
                                "<div class='projectDate'><span>Post time: </span>"+time+"</div>"+           
                                "<div type='hidden' class='downloadElement' id='"+downloadlink+"' onclick='downloadProject(this)'><button type='submit' class='downloadProjectBtn'>Download</button></div>"+
                                "<div class='rating'>"+
                                    "<label for='showRating'></label>"+
                                    "<span class='showRating' id='overall-"+change.doc.id+"'>"+rating+"</span>"+
                                    "<span class='yourRating' id='r-"+change.doc.id+"'></span>"+
                                    "<span class='votes' id='votes-"+change.doc.id+"'></span>"+
                                "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</div>"
                        document.getElementById('projectContainer').innerHTML+=newProjects;

                    }

                }

                if (change.type === "modified") {


                }
                if (change.type === "removed") {
                    document.getElementById('p-'+change.doc.id).outerHTML="";

                }  

            });              

        });

    }else{
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docChanges` property on a snapshot are a list of the changes in the order they occurred. This allows you to perform targeted manipulations of data. Alternatively, the `docs` property provides an in-order list of all of the documents that match the query.

You may want to look into libraries like [lit-html](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/) to make efficient re-rendering possible without doing it manually. However, if you do want to use `docChanges` while preserving order, you will need to look at the `oldIndex` and `newIndex` properties (see [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange#properties_1)) on the change to see where it's supposed to go relative to existing content. A simple example managing docChanges to update an array:

```
const arr = [];

ref.onSnapshot(snap => {
  snap.docChanges.forEach(change => {
    if (change.oldIndex !== -1) {
      arr.splice(change.oldIndex, 1);
    }
    if (change.newIndex !== -1) {
      arr.splice(change.newIndex, 0, change.doc);
    }
  }
});
```

The above code will keep an array updated with the documents from the query in the correct order by splicing it.